# vba to select a range that is written in a cell

Tags: vba, excel, macros, range

I have made a formula to updates the range I need, so for instance cell `A1` will say `A1:B9` (always changing when new data is downloaded).

I need to know how to get my VBA to look at cell `A1` and use that as the range, e.g.

```
ActiveSheet.Range ("a1").select
```

to show a range of `A1:B9` and not just `a1` as a range.

Is this possible??

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range(Range("A1").Value).Select`

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Dim rng as Range
With ActiveSheet
    Set rng = .Range(.Range("A1").Value)
End With
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `With ActiveSheet`?  An unqualified range always references the ActiveSheet.

Comment: @ThomasInzina: I'd say it has at least the purpose of making the user (coder) think about what worksheet he wants to refer to. Under this perspective it's highly preferable to plain `Set rng = Range(Range("A1").Value)`

Comment: I guess it is personal preference.  I would prefer to see `With WorkSheets("Sheet1")` .  I say that because I see a lot of meaningless references that do nothing to add to the readability of the code.  Anyway, you still have the correct answer +1.